# How can I find the perimeter lines of an array of (2d) triangles?

Tags: math, polygon, triangulation

I'm looking to reduce a group of triangulated triangles to a polygon (that is, rejecting all internal lines).  Basically, given an array of triangles, which is assumed triangulated, I want to get ONLY the outside lines, like so:

[image]

Is there a good method of doing that?

I essentially want to populate this function:

```
vector<line> GetPerimeter(vector <triangles>)
{
   ...
}
```

I can think of a few ways of doing it, but they'd all be massive brute recursive tests that could end up being brutal.  Is there a quick n' clever way to do it?

Comment: I guess the fastest and cleverest way depends on what your datastructure looks like. One idea that comes to mind is summing the angles around each vertex. A vertex is "internal" if and only if the angles around it sum to 360° (or 2pi). And of course an edge is internal if and only if it is incident to an internal vertex.

Comment: Can't you just eliminate those edges which belong to two triangles?

Comment: If you want to reduce a group of triangulated triangles to a polygon, please show what your data looks like. Depending on what you're working with there are different things you can do.